# Achartengine graphs in tab view

Tags: android-layout, tabs, achartengine

I am a beginner, and was doing somework arounds with lists and charts. 
I used the same code as supplied from achartengine samples.
My launcher activity, which is deriving from TabActivity has its create method as follows,

```
setContentView(R.layout.tabstrip);
Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
SalesBarChart myChart = new SalesBarChart();
intent = myChart.execute(this);   
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("BarChart").setIndicator("BarChart",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_barchart))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
AverageTemperatureChart myChart1 = new AverageTemperatureChart();
intent = myChart1.execute(this);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_linechart))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
```

My xml file looks like,

```
     <TabHost
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">
           <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
           <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp" />
       </LinearLayout>
```

The same intents i fire in startactivity(intent) on a button click works, but doesnt work in tabs. 
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem in two weeks ago. But I had pieChart in xml layer combine other views.
Anyway, I create an activity for each tab and chart, and call the activities instead of charts.
In one of my activity I have this snipped code:

```
public class FirstChartActivity extends Activity{
    // other code
    protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (hChartView == null) { // first time pie chart is empty
                renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);
                renderer.setLabelsTextSize(14);
                categorySeries = setCategorySeries("First PieChart",
                        myList);
                // draw pie chart with initialized values (myList and colors)
                hChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, categorySeries,
                renderer);
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pch_chart);
                layout.addView(hChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            } else {
                hChartView.repaint();
            }
        }

        protected DefaultRenderer buildCategoryRenderer(int[] colors) {
            DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
            for (int color : colors) {
                SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
                r.setColor(color);
                renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
            }
            return renderer;
        }

        protected CategorySeries setCategorySeries(String chartTitle,
                HashMap<String, Double> hashMap) {
            CategorySeries cs = new CategorySeries(chartTitle);
            Iterator<String> iter = hashMap.keySet().iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                String key = iter.next();
                Double val = hashMap.get(key);
                cs.add(key, val);
            }
            return cs;
        }
    }
```

I hope this code help you.